# Trouble printing objects in ArrayList using Enhanced For Loop

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I cannot get the Product Objects to print out anything using an Enhanced for loop.  Everything comes out null or 0?

The output show this?

```
0null0.0This is the id
0null0.0This is the id
0null0.0This is the id
```

Here's my code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        ArrayList < Product > store1 = new ArrayList < Product > ();
        store1.add(new Product(3, "Nike", 300.0));
        store1.add(new Product(2, "Addidas", 400.0));
        store1.add(new Product(6, "Under Armor", 500.0));
        for (Product y: store1) {
            System.out.println(y + "This is the id");
        }
    }
}

class Product {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public double price;
    public Product(int startId, String startName, double startPrice) {
        startId = id;
        startName = name;
        startPrice = price;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return id + name + price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the main:

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to improve the question. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't paste the code in the comments as you see, it gets messy

Comment: I've put the code in the question for you this time.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to delete the code from the comments

Comment: Try `y.getId()`. Plus in your constructor change the `startId = id;` to `id = startId;`

Comment: @ΣωτήρηςΡαφαήλ No, `Product` has a `toString` that appears to be what the OP wants to use.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes his constructor is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a backward assignments in the constructor:

```
public Product(int startId, String startName, double startPrice) {
        startId = id;
        startName = name;
        price = startPrice;
    }
```

leaving the object uninitialized...

but you mean for sure

```
public Product(int startId, String startName, double startPrice) {
        id = startId;
        name = startName;
        startPrice = price;
    }
```

Comment: Yup.  That was it!!!  Thanks so much.  I messed up my instance variable assignments!

Answer (score 1):

You have your assignments backward in the constructor. It should be:

```
public Product(int startId, String startName, double startPrice) {
    id = startId;       // Not `startId = id;`
    name = startName;   // Not `startName = name;`
    price = startPrice; // Not `price = startPrice;`
}
```

or better yet (and this would have flagged the problem up for you when you tried to compile), don't rely on implicit `this`:

```
public Product(int startId, String startName, double startPrice) {
    this.id = startId;
    this.name = startName;
    this.price = startPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variables the wrong way around in your constructor, i.e.

`startId = id;` should be `id = startId;`

You should also add `@Override` to your `toString()` method.